# How do I use top (or equivalent) to determine if a process is behaving badly?

Tags: linux, top, htop

Are there indicators for when a process has "gone over to the dark side"?

I feel that just using MEM% and CPU% are poor indicators for detecting things such as memory leaks (or other problems, excuse my limited vocabulary) because it's hard to know, without sufficient knowledge of the program, how much memory or CPU the program "should" use.

So how do I suss out truly bad processes vs merely expensive ones?

Comment: `gone over to the dark side`???? If you do not specify exactly what you  mean by that, how can you expect `top` to help you?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is difficult to know exactly how much resources a program "should" use but there are some indicators you can check if there are enough resources for your system to handle the program.

First, we check the PID for the process by (e.g. the process name is dataserver):

```
ps aux | grep dataserver
sybxxx     795 52.9  0.0 1190088 22548 ?       S<sl Jun06 38192:51 /sybase/XXX/ASE-16_0/bin/dataserver
```

Here we know that the process ID is 795, so we make use of **pidstat** command:

```
pidstat -h -r -u -p 795 5
Time       PID   %usr    %system  %guest  %CPU   CPU  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM  Command
1469520679  795  242.80    5.00    0.00  247.80  24    0.00      0.00     53618888  22548   0.02  dataserver
```

From the output, we know that the process is using around 2.4 CPU core while the system got 24 cores installed. Also, the used memory in percentage is around 0.02% in total amount of memory installed.

Apart from such information, I think it would be worth enough to have a general system check to prevent resources shortage.

Firstly, to check the **CPU loading**, you can use the **sar** command.
To determine the bad performance of a system, you would check the following output.

In normal situation, the output of iostat would be similar as follow:

```
sar
12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all      0.70      0.00      0.15      0.01      0.00     99.13
```

The value for %idle should remain high while the value of %user, %system and %iowait should be low for a non-busy system.

For the **disk I/O** problem, you can check the result of **iostat -x**:

```
Device: rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda     0.07     1.58    0.27    1.04    13.72    20.87    26.54     0.01    7.50   3.33   0.43
sdc     4.09   252.47  483.10    5.90 18616.61  2148.57    42.46     5.88   12.03   1.99  97.29
```

This is a bad example, as you can see the percentage of utilization for device sdc has become 97.29% which indicates there is a disk I/O problem.

To check if we have enough memory for the system, take a look on the paging usage:

```
sar -B
10:30:01 AM  pgpgin/s pgpgout/s   fault/s  majflt/s  pgfree/s pgscank/s pgscand/s pgsteal/s    %vmeff
10:40:01 AM   8524.25     47.12    856.03      0.00    263.76      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
10:50:01 AM   8391.64     82.94   1116.50      0.08    377.87      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

As we can see the paging in per second is very high for this server, therefore we can suspect that the system is running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I usually look at the load first. If 2 of the 3 numbers are the top are above 3 then you are heading in the wrong direction. A load over 8 for any of the 3 numbers is a serious problem meaning you are running multiple forks of the one process or your machine just isn't equipped to handle what you are trying to do. Example: running a torque batch server with a lots of jobs on it with too few cores.

Then if one of your processes is using an increasing amount of the CPU, this is also a bad indication of problems with memory leaks or this could also be that you are using components called Chrome/Firefox :) Actually Firefox has suffered badly from using attached plugins such as Skype which lead to overflows in older versions.

Another indicator is a large number of spanned processes of the same type, but not always an issue.

And one of the really early indicator of issues is a process marked [defunct], since it is then disfunctional, like most people I know!